# Saving and loading a dataframe turns lists into strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My pandas dataframe has several columns where 2 columns are a list of values:

```
df['array'][0]
>>> array([ 2.0118325e+00, -2.2446325e+00, -1.6791631e+00,  2.7758152e+00,
        1.3304883e-01, -6.4482675e+00, -2.0737982e+00,  2.0454627e-01]

df['names_array'][0]
>>> ['Verizon', '美国电话电报公司', 'Mobile', 'Sprint', '甲骨文公司', 'Novell', 'Wireless', '威讯', '苹果电脑', 'EE']
```

I'm saving my dataframe with

```
df.to_csv('df.csv', encoding='utf-8', sep='\t', header=True)
```

And loading it with

```
test = pd.read_csv('df.csv', sep='\t', error_bad_lines=False, header = 0, names=['name', 'freq', 'speech', 'array', 'names_array'])
```

I can't figure out if the issue is with saving or loading the dataframe, but when I try to load it the 2 columns that were lists are now strings:

```
test['names_array'][0]
>>> "['Verizon', '美国电话电报公司', 'Mobile', 'Sprint', '甲骨文公司', 'Novell', 'Wireless', '威讯', '苹果电脑', 'EE']"

test['array'][0]
>>> '[ 2.0118325e+00 -2.2446325e+00 -1.6791631e+00  2.7758152e+00\n  1.3304883e-01 -6.4482675e+00 -2.0737982e+00  2.0454627e-01\n -4.7595534e+00  9.9625808e-01 -3.8964446e+00 -5.5855694e+00\n
```

What is the correct way in this case to save and load this data?

Comment: `csv` file is just comma delimited value file. It doesn't store any information about the type of object before it's serialized so you wouldn't expect `read_csv` to magically restore the data type for you. You'll have to manually parse them.

Comment: Got it. What is the correct way to save and load this data then?

Comment: If you want to share python dataframe faithfully, maybe look at pickle: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html

Comment: Or transform your dataframe to an easier to read and share format. i.e. Flatten array columns before sending to csv.

Comment: Okay pickle worked great! Thanks a lot, I didn't think about it